# C#: String comparison fails when comparing with data from a file?

Tags: c#, string, unit-testing, assert

I am loading text into a file for a test that looks like:

```
        File.WriteAllLines(
            template,
            new string[]
            {
                $"Line1:Replaced once",
                $"Line2:Replaced twice",
                $"Line3:Replaced thrice",
                $"Nothing to replace here."
            });
```

and when I load it and try to compare it to string var that looks like:

```
        string expected = string.Join(
            separator: "\n",
            $"Line1:Replaced once",
            $"Line2:Replaced twice",
            $"Line3:Replaced thrice",
            $"Nothing to replace here.",
            string.Empty);
```

The equal comparison fails. I converted both of them to toCharArray and I see that their lengths do not match up. I tried getting rid of the newline separator but the error persists. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Do you know line break in windows is `\r\n`?

Comment: If you're on Windows, the separator would be `\r\n` (or just use `Environment.NewLine`).

Comment: Try it with `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. This is doesn't show how you load the file.

Comment: @shingo thanks for the quick response. changing separator to \r\n fixed it.

Comment: If you want to know what the characters in the file are *read the characters in the file and see what they are*.  You're already reading the file, just *look at what the actual characters are* if you want to see how they're different from what you thought they would be.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the separator that you are using; it's not what windows uses by default. `Environment.NewLine` can be used instead of hardcoded characters.

You can also use the `File.ReadAllText` method to get the file content as a single string instead of getting it back as a series of lines.